# About the division of floating point numbers in C language。

Tags: c

I am a university student. When learning C language, I encountered the problem of floating point division. Can anyone help me to see why the results are different every time I run it. thank you very much.( I am running in a Linux)

My English is not good, hope you can understand the meaning of my question。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    printf("%d\n",b/a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "the problem of dividing floating-point numbers"?

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should listen to your compiler warnings. It should tell you about parameter type mismatch in `printf`. You promise to provide an `int` value but instead you pass a `double`. This is causing undefined behaviour which can include any kind of strange result. If you did not get a warning, turn up warning level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text, especially code, *as text* into your questions.

Comment: `printf( "%lf\n", b / a );`. Specifier `%d` is for `int`.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: [Picture of my comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weDgp.png)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: laihonglin, Save time.  Enable **all** compiler warnings to quickly see the problem with `printf("%d\n",b/a);`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format specifier.

The `%d` former specifier for `printf` expects an `int` as an argument, but you're passing in a `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should instead use `%f` which is for printing a `double`.

```
printf("%f\n",b/a);
```

Comment: Why does this happen if it is %d

Comment: @laihonglin Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @laihonglin Different types can have different sizes and can be passed to a function in different ways.  And because all arguments to `printf` after the first don't have a specific type, those details become important.

Comment: The compiler does not report an error, and the result is always 0 in windows

Comment: @laihonglin That's part of undefined behavior.  There's no expectation of any particular result.

Comment: @Some programmer dude
This kind of code is an error code, and this kind of code is not allowed in C language, right?

Comment: @laihonglin That's right, it's not allowed. Most compilers can actually detect it and emit a warning about it. If it doesn't for you, then you need to enable more warnings when building. With MSVC add the `/W4` build option, with GCC and Clang use `-Wall -Wextra`.